# Removing Images from tf.data.Dataset by their frequency

Tags: python, tensorflow

So i am loading photos inside of tf.data.Dataset.

I want to remove photos, if their labeled counterparts are already present 100 times in dataset. how can i do that? for example if cat photo was already seen 101 time in tf.data.Dataset it would get removed.

Now data is already in tf.data.Dataset format, its loaded like this:

```py
dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(DATADIR, image_size=(2044, 1533), batch_size = None)
```